# Refactoring in jQuery (following DRY principles)

Tags: jquery

```
$dltDiv.click(function(){
                    $seatdiv.css("background-color","#42de18"); 
                    $ticketRowDiv.hide();
                    price = price-15.50; 
                    $('#price h1').html('$'+price);
                });

$seatdiv.click(function(){
                    $seatdiv.css("background-color","#42de18"); 
                    $ticketRowDiv.hide();
                    price = price-15.50; 
                    $('#price h1').html('$'+price);
                });
```

How could I make the same code in one function and be called seperately?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a named function and bind for both events:

```
function handleClick(){
  $seatdiv.css("background-color","#42de18"); 
  $ticketRowDiv.hide();
  price = price-15.50; 
  $('#price h1').html('$'+price);
}

$dltDiv.click(handleClick);
$seatdiv.click(handleClick);
```

Or you can combine the jQuery objects:

```
$dltDiv.add($seatdiv).click(function(){
  $seatdiv.css("background-color","#42de18"); 
  $ticketRowDiv.hide();
  price = price-15.50; 
  $('#price h1').html('$'+price);
});
```

Comment: var handleClick = function (){...} has the same endresult

Comment: @TigOldBitties ~ that is a trivial point, in the context of this question.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: Yes, in most situations it doesn't make a difference, however there is a difference as assigning an anonymous function to a variable is done at runtime.